# Garbage collection too slow

Tags: python, pandas, garbage-collection

I have a function foo() that creates a BIG list (and then converts it to a pandas dataframe)

When I time it, it runs a bit slow, but reasonable:

```
timeit.Timer('foo()', setup="from __main__ import foo").timeit(number=1)
6.69
```

However, that's not the time I get during execution, because the garbage collection is disabled.  It runs 2x slower, if the garbage collector is enabled:

```
timeit.Timer('foo()', setup="from __main__ import foo \ngc.enable()").timeit(number=1)
20.31
```

When is it ok to disable the garbage collector? Should I do so from within foo()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to python documentation `you can disable the collector if you are sure your program does not create reference cycles.` If don't want automatic GC to happen during execution of foo. It makes sense to do something like this

```
def foo():
   gc.disable()
   // Your logic
   gc.enable()
```

Link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html